# Copy bytes from smaller types to bigger type

Tags: c++, memory

So, I want to retain information of two `short` into one `int` for sending over the network later (this is just a demonstration, no network code here). I copied two bytes of each `short` number into the `prim` (primitive) variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    unsigned int prim = 0;
    short major = 0x0001;
    short minor = 0x0000;
    prim = 0;
    memcpy(&prim, &major, 2);
    memcpy(&prim+2,&minor, 2);
    std::cout << "Prim: " << prim << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS
}
```

If I copy the `major` first, then `minor` (as written in the code above) later, I will get the correct output:

```
Prim: 1
```

Because my CPU is little endian, the binary representation should be:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

However, if I change the order, meaning `minor` first then `major` later like this:

```
memcpy(&prim, &minor, 2);
memcpy(&prim+2,&major, 2);
```

I get a 0.

```
Prim: 0
```

Why? It is supposed to be:

```
00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000
```

Which is equal to 65536.

Comment: Next to the already given answer: If you want to be sure about the byte size of types, at least use uintXX_t.  There is no guarantee about the size of int and short.

Comment: `00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000` is 65536.

Comment: @stefaanv The problem is not the size of the type. Haven't worked with pointer size for a long time, I forgot each type of pointer point to different sizes, and assumed it always points to one byte.

Comment: It is a problem, you just don't see it because it happens to be the way you assume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `&prim + 2` points to 8 bytes (2 × sizeof(int)) after `&prim`.

You need to cast it to a `char*` to make the pointers increase by bytes.

```
memcpy((char*)&prim+2, &major, 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

A more portable way of putting integers into larger integers is by shifting.

```
uint16_t lo = 1;
uint16_t hi = 2;
uint32_t all = (hi << 16) + lo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides fixing the error in calculating correct poiters you may avoid all this pointer calculations by using unions:

```
#include <iostream>

    union two_shorts_t {
      unsigned int prim ;
      struct shorts_t {
          short major;
          short minor;
      } shorts;
    } ;

int main ()
{    
    two_shorts_t values;

    values.shorts.major=1;
    values.shorts.minor=0;
    std::cout << "Prim: " << values.prim << std::endl;

    values.shorts.major=0;
    values.shorts.minor=1;
    std::cout << "Prim: " << values.prim << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is actually NICE. Thanks.